# How to remove repeated array elements and keep first occurrence in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following numpy array with size (5,2):

```
A = [[5,6]
     [4,3]
     [2,1]
     [4,3]
     [8,9]]
```

I want to remove any repeated rows (so in this case [4,3]) and keep the first occurrence and return what looks like:

```
A = [[5,6]
     [4,3]
     [2,1]
     [8,9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Function *numpy.unique* can help you to extract unique values from an array. Specify the *axis* parameter to choose the axis to operate on.
Try this

```
np.unique(A, axis=0)
```

to extract unique rows.
*numpy.unique* will return a sorted array. If you want to retrieve original order, you can use *return_index=True* parameter to return indices of first appearances of the unique elements, and then get these elements from the original array.
For your example, this will work:

```
A[np.sort(np.unique(a, return_index=True, axis=0)[1])]
```

Comment: Tried it on a more complicated example and it doesn't remove them repeated rows or keep the order

Comment: @Iceans I'm sorry for missleading you. np.unique doesn't keep the order, it returns elements in sorted order. I updated my answer with an idea of how you can keep the order.

Comment: @Iceans Also, make sure that your axis parameter is right. If it still doesn't work, please bring on your more complicated example.

Comment: @redgen is there a way to message you some code? I still cant get it to work

Comment: @Iceans unfortunatelly, there are no private messages on stackoverflow. You can edit your question and add this code or add some external link. I would be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```py
A = [[5,6],
     [4,3],
     [2,1],
     [4,3],
     [8,9]]
B = set(map(tuple, A))
print(B)
```

[image]

without loosing order :

```
uniq = []
for i in A:
    if not i in uniq:
        uniq.append(i)
print('l=%s' % str(A))
print('uniq=%s' % str(uniq))
```

[image]

Comment: It's too bad you loose the order of the list.

Comment: true. i added both option.

Comment: I am working with a numpy array not a list. Arrays do not have the append feature but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use value converted to string as key.  Unwrap dict to get list of unique elements.

```
list(dict([[str(x),x] for x in A]).values())
```